# JQuery Smart Spinner : Callback property is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to call function named `Test()`. Now When I click on up-down button of J Query Smart Spinner, then Test() should be called. For that I am using callback property. But  My problem is that, `Test()` is executed one time only. What should I do?

My Code is...

```
function Test(id) {
    //alert($(id).val());
    var final = ($(id).val());
    final = parseFloat(final).toFixed(2);
    $(search_txt).val(final);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#spin_size').spinit({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 10, 
        stepInc: 0.01, 
        width: 69, 
        height: 30, 
        btnWidth: 20, 
        callback: Test('#spin_size') 
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="size_from">
    <div class="size_from_space">
        <input type="text" id="spin_size" value="0" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `callback` property should be a function:

```
callback: function() {
    Test('#spin_size');
}
```